# CRM takes 1 hour to convert an email in a queue into a history record for the contact

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trialling CRM 4.0 and have noticed that if one of my contacts sends an email then it sits in the queue for an hour before it is also copied into the contacts history.

Is there a job or workflow controlling this?
Can it be sped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the workflow behind it isn't running quickly enough.

If you go to Administration and Workflow admin (I think thats what it's called) you can change the frequency of the workflow to a shorter interval.